# how can i know if radio button has been selected in scala

Tags: swing, scala, radio-button

I used: RadioButton scala gui object - but I didn't find a function that tells if a button has been selected.
In Java JRadioButton has isSelected function, but i want to use only scala objects.

```
 val compareRadios = List(new RadioButton("Description"), new RadioButton("Id"))
 def isSelected = ???
```

Comment: Share us your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer for this [scala-swing](https://github.com/scala/scala-swing) API can be found [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/scala-swing/#scala.swing.RadioButton):

```
def selected: Boolean
```

For your buttons list you can use:

```
compareRadios.find(_.selected)
```

which returns `Option(RadioButton)`. The result will be `None` if nothing is selected or `Some(RadioButton)`.

If you use [ButtonGroup](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/scala-swing/#scala.swing.ButtonGroup) to group your radio buttons, then you can use `ButtonGroup` method:

```
def selected: Option[AbstractButton]
```